# single mvc controller for multiple views

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an application designed using Angular JS. I am using a single server side controller (MVC controller) for 2 views. But now there is a need to determine which view is loading the controller as the same controller gets called when I load either of the views. I just want the  URL of the view which called the controller. I've tried using the HTTPContext object but it doesn't give me any property by which I can differentiate the 2 pages. Is it because angular doesn't show the entire URL? If yes then is there any way to differentiate between the 2 calls to the controller?

Comment: Why do you want to know what view is calling controller action? If there should be different behavior for different views, you should call different actions.

Comment: You can use different query string for different views.

Answer (score 0):

> *I just want the URL of the view which called the controller*

Override `OnActionExecuting` in your controller and add current url to ViewBag:

```
protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    ViewBag.Url = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri; 
}
```

Accessing from view:

```
@ViewBag.Url
```